# Replace brackets to span javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, colors, html

I want to manipulate the DOM a bit and need some help.

That's my HTML-Markup:

```
<span class=“content“> This is my content: {#eeeeee}grey text{/#eeeeee} {#f00000}red text{/#f00000}</span>
```

That's how it should be:

```
<span class="content">This is my content: <span style="color:#eeeeee;">grey text</span><span style="color:#f00000;">red text</span></span>
```

The script should replace the brackets with span tags to change the font-color.
The color should the same that is in the bracket.

My approach:

```
function regcolor(element) {
    var text = element.innerText;
    var matches = text.match(/\{(#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6})\}([\s\S]*)\{\/\1\}/gim);
    if (matches != null) {
        var arr = $(matches).map(function (i, val) {
            var input = [];
            var color = val.slice(1, 8);
            var textf = val.slice(9, val.length - 10);
            var html = "<span style=\"color: " + color + ";\">" + textf + "</span>";
            input.push(html);
            return input;
        });

        var input = $.makeArray(arr);

        $(element).html(input.join(''));
    };
```

But it's not working very well and i'm not feeling good with the code, it looks messy.
And the script looses the content that's not in the brackets("This is my content:").

Anyone a idea?

Comment: do you plan on nesting bracket blocks? like `{first}some text {second}here{/second}{/first}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used just a touch of jQuery, but it could easily do without. It's just a regular expression string replacement.

```
$('.content').each(function() {
  var re = /\{(#[a-z0-9]{3,6})\}(.*?)\{\/\1\}/g;
  //          ^                 ^
  //          $1                $2

  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(re, function($0, $1, $2) {
    return '<span style="color: ' + $1 + '">' + $2 + '</span>';
  });
});
```

I'm using a back-reference to properly match the opening and closing braces.

**Update**

Could be even shorter:

```
$('.content').each(function() {
  var re = /\{(#[a-z0-9]{3,6})\}(.*?)\{\/\1\}/g,
  repl = '<span style="color: $1">$2</span>';

  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(re, repl);
});
```

**Look mum, no jQuery**

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('content');

for (var i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; ++i) {
  var re = /\{(#[a-z0-9]{3,6})\}(.*?)\{\/\1\}/g,
  repl = '<span style="color: $1">$2</span>';

  nodes[i].innerHTML = nodes[i].innerHTML.replace(re, repl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex to replace the matches directly:

```
function regcolor2(element) {
    var text = element.html();
    var i = 0;
    var places = text.replace(/\{(#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6})\}([\s\S]*)\{\/\1\}/gim, function( match ) {
        var color = match.slice(1, 8);
        var textf = match.slice(9, match.length - 10);
        var html = "<span style=\"color: " + color + ";\">" + textf + "</span>";
        return html;
    });

    $(element).html(places);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it can be shorter with jquery and this method or syntax

```
$(function() {

$('.content').html($('.content').text().replace( new RegExp('{(.*?)}(.*?){\/.*?}','g'), '<span style="color:$1">$2</span>'));

});
```